# Python error: ImportError: No module named QtWebKit

Tags: python, anki

I just installed Anki, but when I try to run the program, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/anki", line 7, in <module>
    import aqt
File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import *
File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebView, QWebSettings
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit
```

I installed all the QTweb packages mentioned in this post: [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253348], but the same issue remains.

Comment: Try to missed dependencies with `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4 python-qt4`.

Comment: @N0rbert : still the same error, unfortunately